# SharePoint REST API

Tags: javascript, rest, api, sharepoint

I need your help. I want to build a form on website x which send data to a Sharepoint to domain y. I have the Office 365 Enterprise - Business Essentials License

1. Is that even possible?
2. What an where do I have to setup Office365 (API etc.)
3. Hot to connect via SharePoint REST API?

Can you guys give me an example for my HTML code. I have the same forms also in Sharepoint:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Test</h1>

        <!-- HTML Form (wrapped in a .bootstrap-iso div) -->
        <div class="bootstrap-iso">
         <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <form method="post">
             <div class="form-group ">
              <label class="control-label " for="name">
               Name
              </label>
              <input readonly class="form-control" id="name" name="name" value="" type="text"/>
             </div>
             <div class="form-group ">
              <label class="control-label " for="date">
               Date
              </label>
              <input readonly class="form-control" id="date" name="date" value="" type="text"/>
             </div>
            <div class="form-group ">
              <label class="control-label " for="time">
               Time
              </label>
              <input readonly class="form-control" id="time" name="time" value="" type="text"/>
             </div>
             <div class="form-group ">
              <label class="control-label " for="location">
               Location
              </label>
              <input readonly class="form-control" id="location" name="location" value="" type="text"/>
             </div>
             <div class="form-group">
              <div>
               <button class="btn btn-primary " name="submit" type="submit">
                Submit
               </button>
              </div>
             </div>
            </form>
           </div>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>




    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This will be blocked in all modern browsers for a Cross-Origin Request.  You need to setup your sites to allow cross origin requests between them: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors

Answer (score 0):

Apart from CORS issue that Jeff mentioned in the comment, you need an App Registration in your SP Online environment:
https://yourtenantname.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/appregnew.aspx
[image]

and then assigning App permisssions at:
https://yourtenantname.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx
[image]

Permissions XML:

```
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
       <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web" 
        Right="FullControl"/>
    </AppPermissionRequests>
```

and then trusting the app.
These steps will provide you with an client id and secret that you need to use to implement OAuth 2.0 (authorization code grant flow or implicit grant flow depending upon your web app), which will get you the access token that you can use to authenticate SharePoint Rest API calls through authorization header.